# Make a combination of shape using css3 as a background of website and the shape must be dynamic

Tags: html, css

I've  combined the shapes to make  a background of website using css3. The problem is the shapes are not stick to each other as I put it as a background. The shapes are separated and the text from the website are hidden behind the shapes.  This is the code.

```css
#home {
  border-bottom: 200px solid black;
  border-left: 250px solid black;
  border-right: 250px solid black;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#home:before {
  border-bottom: 300px solid black;
  border-left: 350px solid transparent;
  border-right: 350px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: -250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -300px;
  width: 0;
}

#tri {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-left: 199px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 250px;
}

#tri:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -186px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 135%;
  background: purple;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 41deg);
}

#tri:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 49px;
  right: -280px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 135%;
  background: purple;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -41deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="home"></div>
  <div id="tri"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add z-index to your shapes, so the shapes sit behind the body.  This is assuming the text will be inputted outside of these divs.

```
   #home {
      border-bottom: 200px solid black;
      border-left: 250px solid black;
      border-right: 250px solid black;
      background: black;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 30px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      z-index: -1;
    }

    #home:before {
      border-bottom: 300px solid black;
      border-left: 350px solid transparent;
      border-right: 350px solid transparent;
      content: "";
      height: 0;
      left: -250px;
      position: absolute;
      top: -300px;
      width: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    #tri {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 12px;
      margin-left: 199px;
      margin-top: 80px;
      height: 10px;
      width: 250px;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    #tri:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: -186px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 135%;
      background: purple;
      -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
      -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
      -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
      -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
      transform: skew(0deg, 41deg);
      z-index: -1;
    }

    #tri:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 49px;
      right: -280px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 135%;
      background: purple;
      -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
      -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
      -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
      -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
      transform: skew(0deg, -41deg);
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: @Ithomas112 thanks.. It's work.. do u know how to make the combination of shape attach each other dynamically?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean, have you got an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If the answer is right, you should mark it as best answer.